# How do I determine the Internal Energy of ammonia at a pressure in temperature when the steam table doesn't say it

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I just bought a steam table for my thermodynamics class since they don't allow use to use the one from the book for the tests. This one is different from the one in my textbook as it doesn't give the internal energy values for saturated ammonia at a certain temperature and pressure. Is there any way that I could calculate these values to use them in my work?

Comment: Do the tables that you have include the enthalpy, h, at the values that you're interested in? If so, you can can find the internal energy as u = h - Pv. 

If it's just a problem of not having values for a specific temperature of interest, then you could find the two (T,h) pairs which straddle the T that you're interested in and perform a linear interpolation between them